# creating an extension for c# application which calls static functions defined in host program

Tags: c#

I want to create engine for extensions, right now I have a basic class called "Module" which contains lot of virtual functions, each extension is a class that inherits "Module" and override the functions (mostly hooks) with own code.

I want to be able to put these extensions to separate binary and to load it "on the fly".

I created a simple handler for loading these plugins:

```
    public static bool LoadMod(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.Reflection.Assembly library = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
                if (library == null)
                {
                    Program.Log("Unable to load " + path + " because the file can't be read", true);
                    return false;
                }
                Type[] types = library.GetTypes();
                Type type = library.GetType("wmib.RegularModule");
                Type pluginInfo = null;
                foreach (Type curr in types)
                {
                    if (curr.IsAssignableFrom(type))            
                    {
                        pluginInfo = curr;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (pluginInfo == null)
                {
                    Program.Log("Unable to load " + path + " because the library contains no module", true);
                    return false;
                }
                Module _plugin = (Module)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginInfo);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            core.handleException(fail);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is that these modules are calling functions in static classes that I have in host application. Is it possible to create some "skeleton" of this static class in source code of extension? I tried creating the class in the second source code with empty functions of same name and parameters, but that doesn't work for some reason (every time I attempt to load it I get: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.mscorlib  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke)

Here is example of what I want to be able to do:

There is a host application that contains extension handler, and some own static functions.
The host application loads the module from binary file and insert it to some array of modules (this is what is done in constructor of every class that inherits "Module". This module contains some functions which are calling the static functions of host application. What I need to be able to do is being able to call the static function that is defined in source code of host application, even in source code of plugin, which doesn't contain the static function's code. I hope it's clear a bit :)

Comment: Does that static class have dependencies in the host?

Comment: yes it has, basically it's not possible to "copy paste" it to module, because I would likely have to copy whole code of whole host application

Comment: @Hardrada actually I just want to create some API functions this extension could communicate with host through, (change the existing stuff in application etc)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's actually not that hard as I thought, I just referenced the host binary to extension, which enabled all static elements and classes of host in the extension.